# Curly brace expansion: from tcsh to zsh

Tags: zsh, tcsh, zshrc, zsh-alias

In `~/.tcshrc`, I have the following aliases:

```
alias   trash   'echo  ./*{~,.bak,.save} ./.*{~,.bak,.save} ./#*#'
alias   trashit 'rm -f ./*{~,.bak,.save} ./.*{~,.bak,.save} ./#*#'
```

How can I implement the same in `zsh`? The curly brace expansion seems to fail unless all criteria are met.

Comment: zsh fails the command if any glob fails for safety reasons. Try `|` pattern and local nullglob `(N)` like this: `echo ./*(~|.bak|.save)(N) ./.*(~|.bak|.save)(N) ./\#*\#(N)`. Read more: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204944/252440, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/298625

Comment: Shorter one with `dotglob`: `echo ./*(~|.bak|.save)(DN) ./\#*\#(N)`

Comment: Thank you @PhuNgo. This is an acceptable answer for me.

Comment: @PhuNgo So, why not put this into an answer, instead of a comment?